# passing variable from controller to the view in api rest codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I have two controllers, in the first which extends CI_Controller where I load my views ( represents my home page), in the second which extends REST_controller I have a class where I load my models and functions to get my arrays from sql requests to send them to my views. 
So I'm not that I understood well how rest works but I want to know if my architecture is good like I explained.
I want also to know how I can display simple variables using rest, I mean if for example I have a function in my model such :

```
public function nb_bananas()
    {
            $query = $this->db->query('SELECT count(*) as nb 
                FROM bananas
            '); 
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $query->result_array();

            }else{
                return NULL;
            }
    }
```

before using rest I used to get nb of bananas in controller such as :

```
$data['nb_bananas]=$this->MyModel->nb_bananas();
```

and I display the number of bananas in my view such as :

```
<?php echo $nb_bananas[0]['nb'] ?>
```

My question is, now when I'm using rest I should get my return sql request in the controler such as :

```
public function nb_bananas_get(){
$nb_bananas=$this->MyModel->nb_bananas();
if ($nb_bananas){
 $this->response($nb_bananas,REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);                     
}
else{$this->response([
                    'status' => FALSE,
                    'message' => 'No users were found'
                ], REST_Controller::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);}
```

Is that correct ?
And what is the simple way display just the nb_bananas in my view without using any buttun like in a Dashboard?
Or maybe even if in restful I can use the old method to pass my variable to the views ?

Thank you for your answers.